# How can I use ReactNative PushNotificationIOS with the UserNotifications framework?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

After following all the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html), didReceiveLocalNotification is never called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

This causes the listeners to never fire:

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('localNotification', () => {
  console.log("never called")
});
```

The local notifications are received normally and [didReceiveNotificationResponse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter?language=objc) is called, but PushNotificationiOS does not support didReceiveNotificationResponse.

How do I use React native's PushNotificationiOS library for iOS 11? It appears to rely on didReceiveLocalNotification being called, but it has been deprecated for a while now and is not working at all on iOS 11. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're using the new `UserNotifications` framework, you can't use the old app delegate method at the same time.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. This specifically relates to using React native's PushNotificationIOS library. It is not working as the docs imply it will.

Comment: The cause is as I stated; React Native is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. The PushNotificationsIOS docs say that the above code should work. Your comment is correct, but does not answer the question and the other question is asking something different.